# Wrapper script to run a particular job in Control m

Tags: unix, control-m

I have to write a wrapper script to run 3 jobs in control M if a variable is Y i.e

```
$EOM_1=’Y’ [incase of End of Month true] 
$EOM_1=’N’ [incase of End of Month false]
```

i.e `if $EOM_1=’Y’ run jobs like ${DirTOOLS}/WaitUnitFileExists.sh $APIS/files/tr/chqload/local/INWUSD.dat 60 05 30`

Answer (score 0):

Why is the wrapper script needed?  You can do this with the Job Defintions within Control-M. In the DAYS field in the job scheduling defintion for the job to run the last day of the month you would put L1.

For the Job that will run all but the last day of the month you specify -L1 in the DAYS field.  For the job that has to wait on a file, run the Control-M File watcher utility that will then add the condition for the job or force the job in to run.